# UICollectionview scrollToItemAtIndexPath, not loading visible cells until animation complete

Tags: swift, animation, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `UICollectionView` with 142 Cells. 7.5 are visible at any one time.

I'm moving a cell from `indexPath` 0 to say 100.
But I also want to scroll to that new position.

The code below works fine. But it animates the move and scroll, but then loads the cells in front of and behind the central/moved cell afterwards.
I think its because the cells are reusable. but with 142, I can't pre-load all of them

Its not the nicest effect, I would like to pre-load the cells surrounding the new position, 4 before and 4 after `indexPath` 100, and then see the animation of the move and scroll. can you help please?

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(animationSpeed, animations: {() -> Void in
    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem:self.indexPathSelected.row, 
                                                 inSection:0), 
                                                 atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, 
                                                 animated: true)

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I have found, is to add a few seconds to the animation. That way the cells are loaded when the scroll arrives

Comment: Show examples of doing that

Answer (score 18):

> Swift 3.0 OR up
>
> add "view.layoutIfNeeded()" before implementing scrollToItem method, Ideally in viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
view.layoutIfNeeded()
  colView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)}
```

Answer (score 7):

I use dispatch_async to update the UI and it works.

```
let numberOfSections = self.collectionView.numberOfSections()
let numberOfRows = self.collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

    if numberOfRows > 0 {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
        })
    }
```

Comment: This also works when you're trying to scroll within a viewWillAppear(_:). For example, I just did this to start with item #2 out of 5 indices so my collection view starts in the middle instead of at the beginning when the view controller appears.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to use `DispatchQueue`.

Swift 4.2:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let index = items.firstIndex(of: preSelectedItem) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Politta's answer is correct. Here's how you can implement what you want in Objective C:

```
- (void)scrollToBottomWithoutAnimation{
    NSInteger lastVisibleRowIndex = (NSInteger)self.myItems.count - 1;
    NSIndexPath *lastVisibleIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: lastVisibleRowIndex inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastVisibleIndexPath atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
}
```

​

In your viewWillAppear method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self scrollToBottomWithoutAnimation];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` before calling `scrollToBottomWithoutAnimation`