# UIcollectionView scrollToitemAtIndexPath does not work for non visible cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS and Swift.

Have managed to create a UICollectionView with custom LayoutAttributes and reusable custom cell which calculates the height of it for an image.
That's all great. Works fine and I can scroll manually. all good.

The problem is that I want to programatically scroll to the Nth indexPath but scrollToItemAtIndexPath seems to work only for the visible ones.

So I have to 2 columns of images which on iphone 5S shows 9 images. 
The total number of images is 31.

So using ScrollToItemAtIndexPath of the collectionView works up to the 9th item.

However, when I try to scroll programatically further, say 12th, it doesn't work. 
The weird bit is that if scroll manually, and then call the code, it works.
So I debug a bit and have seen that only the first 9 cells are calculated with a height. 
Would that be the problem? If so, how could I make it work?

Have tried suggestions of using didLayoutSubviews and others but it didnt work.

At the moment, I am using the didSelectItemAtIndexPath collectionView func to scroll programmatically.

EDIT:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = self.collectionView(self.collectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
            let lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(lastItemIndex, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredVertically, animated: true)
}
```

Even if I hardcode the number of the index path (e.g. 12) it will still not work.
If more information is required please let me know.

Am I missing something here?

many thanks.

Comment: Please add some of your code to your question. When do you want to scroll? How does your code look like to scroll to your given NSIndexPath?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "At the moment, I am using the didSelectItemAtIndexPath collectionView func to scroll programmatically." That may have something to do with your issue. Also, yes, please post some code to help

Comment: @beeef thanks for your quick reply, here is the code for scrolling.

Comment: @DougMead thanks for your reply. I have a navigation from another ViewController passing an array of objects to be used in this UICollectionView along with information on which index to navigate to when navigation finishes. However this was not working as well and I made it a bit simpler by utilising the didSelectItemAtIndexPath where I tried to navigate to a specific indexPath.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed the issue then?

Comment: @DougMead No, not really, the problem persists.. It is rather strange. As if the cells dont yet exist but the indexPaths do. So I can only scroll (programatically) to the visible ones..

Comment: That's very strange. It seems like something else is going on. Have you tried the scrollToItem.. anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @DougMead tried to in the didLayoutSubviews()  method and still the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm. didLayoutSubviews() gets called many times (may even be getting called repeatedly while scrolling), so that may not be the best spot. Also, I noticed you set scroll position to the center. Just to be clear (in case you don't already know), UICollectionView fights having white space. So, If you are trying to scroll to the last item, for instance, it will not scroll to the center. It will remain at the bottom.

Comment: ... the same goes for if you were trying to scroll the top item to the bottom position. The only other thing I can think of is that you accidentally placed your items in sections (you're always scrolling to section: 0)

Comment: many thanks @DougMead. I will try a simple case again with a demo project just with a UICollectionView and see what I might be doing wrong. Will get back to you.

Comment: mox, did you find a resolution to this. I am currently facing the same problem

Comment: No yet @Nitesh. Got sidetracked. will get back to you once I have results.

Comment: try collectionView.contentOffset

Answer (score 6):

You should call the method scrollToItemAtIndexPath in the viewDidAppear, that way, the cellForItemAtIndexPath is already called.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: false)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had initially upvoted Lilo's answer but I noticed that adding the code to viewDidAppear caused my horizontal collectionView to abruptly scroll/animate to the the index I wanted it scroll to.

The correct way to do it [is from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42366084/4833705)

In viewWillAppear, before you call `collectionView.scrollToItem`, call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` and there won't be an abrupt visual scroll when the scene appears.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    view.layoutIfNeeded() // call this before you call scrollToItem

    let lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastItemPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: Scrolling doesn't work in viewWillAppear unfortunately. Even if I call view.layoutIfNeeded() beforehand. However, my codebase is Objective C. Does it matter?

Comment: @ErayAlparslan it worked for me in Swift, I can’t speak on Obj-C. Try viewDidLayoutSubviews but use a bool to make sure it runs once. For ex **var didLayoutSubviewsRun = false** then in viewDidLayoutSubviews if it’s false, change it to true then add the cv.scrollToItem afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked for me once I scrolled it in the main thread.

Comment: If the answer worked upvote it, it helps other people.cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when I tried to scroll to non visible cells and to get that cell at indexPath:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: false)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    // here you can get a cell
}
```